# Pattern Matching in scala. What is the behavior when a parameter exhibits polymorhism or is a child class::

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, polymorphism, pattern-matching

I am new to scala I have a bit of experience in java. In the pattern matching section of their website they mentioned that when a parameter is passed to a function different logic can be implemented based on the reference type of the parameter. If so then what would the behavior when a parameter which extends many classes and interfaces is passed to pattern match containing all those classes and interfaces that it implement?
If only the first class/interface is implemented what could be a work around to implement all the logic related to all the classes/interfaces that it implements?

[image: Code from scala website]

[Link to website](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html).

Comment: The first half of your question answers itself. The second half about the "workaround" is unclear: if you want to do multiple things, go and do multiple things, you don't even need semicolons for that, just keep appending statements until you're done. I'm not sure what the image of the code is supposed to symbolize. Also, is the `java` tag really needed here?

Comment: I added the Java tag because I know that language pretty well and if required anybody could give some analogy from it that's it nothing more :)  Anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that a `match` statement will execute only the first `case` that matches, it will not check or execute later matches (otherwise  `case _` would always be executed).

There is no "work-around" because this isn't a bug or a limitation, it is a very useful feature of the language.

---

It sounds as if you have a number of different `trait`s each of which has different behaviour and you want to execute the behaviour for all the traits.

The best way to do this is to write separate functions to match against each trait (`Sum` `Var` etc.) and call them one by one on the `Tree` instance. You can make a sequence of these and use `foldLeft` to apply each of them in turn. Since your `derive` function returns a new `Tree` instance you need to be clear about which order you want to apply the operations.

It remains unclear to me why you have a single object that represents both a `Var` and a `Const`, so I suspect that there is a deeper problem with your data structures.

Comment: Oh the code was given in their website in the pattern matching section and I too dint understand it so I posted it.... :)    So the pattern matching is like a switch statement(of Java) in which the cases only look for wethere or not the parameter is an instanceOf certain class and executes the logic accordingly. Thank you for the help